# JavaScript Console Program

Tags: javascript, windows, cmd, console, console-application

I was wondering...
Could I make a console application for Windows using a JavaScript-like script...
Such code as:

```
window.console.write("Hello, World!");
var useless = window.prompt("Press a key...");
```

And also I was wondering if such a code could be compiled into an `EXE` that could be called in a batch-file. I am aware of a possible solution using node.js, but this is not quite what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance!
~CSS

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like [electron](http://electron.atom.io/)

Comment: @JaredRummler Can Electron apps be compiled into a `.exe`?

Comment: @cascading-style Can you explain why Node.js is not quite what you're looking for? A batch file that runs a JavaScript script in Node.js sounds like a nice option to me.

Comment: @FreekdeBruijn 1) I don't know the first thing about node.js, How it works, or how to use it. 2) I am looking for an easy way to write an executable `.exe` program, and it has to be as small as possible, preferrably not depending on external libraries.

Comment: [Universal Windows Platform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the approach described by Stoyan Stefanov in his article [Make your javascript a Windows .exe](http://www.phpied.com/make-your-javascript-a-windows-exe/). He explains how you can use the [jsc JScript compiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7435xtz6(v=vs.100).aspx) (which is part of the .NET framework) to create executables. According to the [JScript article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript), JScript is very similar (or even equal) to JavaScript.

A simple `Hello.js` example (slightly modified) from the article by Stoyan:

```
var dateToday = new Date();
var randomNumber = Math.random();
print('Hello, \ntoday is ' + dateToday + '\nand this is random - ' + randomNumber);
```

Compiling can be done with a command like this (search for the location of a .NET framework on your machine):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\jsc.exe Hello.js
```

The output should look like this:

```
Hello,
today is Fri Oct 21 23:54:43 UTC+1 2016
and this is random - 0.5690976188374206
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help! You guys are great!